# Developing an encoder/decoder for image modification

Tags: python, machine-learning, image-processing, keras, conv-neural-network

On the project I am currently working on, my goal is to train a neural network to convert images of circles to ellipses in a way that models convolution/blurring in real imaging processes.

What remains is to construct a neural network, preferably a CNN, that has the desired results - i.e. takes an image with circles as an input and returns an image with ellipses. However, I have not been able to do this. At best, neural nets (including CNNs) that I have used so far have at best returned blurred images of the circles. I can't tell whether it is the fault of the neural network or the fault of the preprocessing code I am using.

I am a beginner in machine learning, and I read that convolutional neural networks are the best architecture to use for image processing. Hence, I have attempted to develop a CNN for this purpose. Somebody suggested to use an encoder/decoder model for this problem, but I do not know how to do this.

```
#First, importing the necessary modules:

import keras
from keras.datasets import mnist
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Flatten, Activation, Reshape
from keras.layers import Input, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, UpSampling2D
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from collections import OrderedDict
import itertools
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as patches
import random
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
import math
from math import sqrt
from keras.models import Model, load_model

#Next, creating and storing the input (circle) and output (ellipse) images:

def create_blank_image(size):
    data = np.ndarray(shape=(size, size))
    for i in range(0, size):
        for j in range(0, size):
            data[[i], [j]] = 0
    #print(data)

    return data

def circle_randomizer():
    number_of_circles = random.randint(4,10)
    intensity = np.ndarray(shape=(128, 128))
    #print(number_of_circles)
    radius_list = []


    for i in range(number_of_circles):
        radius_list.append(random.uniform(8, 10))
    #print(radius_list)

    center_coords = np.zeros((2,1))    
    center_coords[[0],[0]] = random.uniform(0,size)
    center_coords[[1],[0]] = random.uniform(0,size)

    for i in range(number_of_circles):
      #temp_array = np.ndarray(shape=(2,1))
      #temp_array[[0],[0]] = random.uniform(0,size)
      #temp_array[[1],[0]] = random.uniform(0,size)

      if i > 0:
          j = 0
          #print(i,j)
          while j in range(i):
              #print(i,j)
              #print(center_coords)
              temp_array = np.ndarray(shape=(2,1))
              temp_array[[0],[0]] = random.uniform(0,size)
              temp_array[[1],[0]] = random.uniform(0,size)
              #while sqrt((center_coords[[0],[i]] - center_coords[[0],[j]])**2 + (center_coords[[1],[i]] - center_coords[[1],[j]])**2) < radius_list[i] + radius_list[j]:
              while sqrt((temp_array[[0],[0]] - center_coords[[0],[j]])**2 + (temp_array[[1],[0]] - center_coords[[1],[j]])**2) < radius_list[i] + radius_list[j]:               
                  temp_array[[0],[0]] = random.uniform(0,size)
                  temp_array[[1],[0]] = random.uniform(0,size)
                  j = 0
              center_coords = np.concatenate((center_coords,temp_array), axis = 1)          
              j = j + 1
              #print('loop ran ' + str(j) + ' times')

    return radius_list, center_coords

def image_creator(centers, radii, img_data, size):
    x = np.arange(1, size, 1)
    y = np.arange(1, size, 1)

    for c in range(len(centers)):
        x0 = centers[[c],[0]]
        y0 = centers[[c],[1]]
        radius = radii[c]
        for i in range(0, size-1):
            for j in range(0, size-1):
                height2 = radius**2 - (x[i]-x0)**2 - (y[j]-y0)**2
                if height2 >= 0:
                    img_data[[i], [j]] = sqrt(radius**2 - (x[i]-x0)**2 - (y[j]-y0)**2)

    return img_data

def make_ellipses(size, radii, center_coords):
    # idea: use a random number generator to create a random rotation of the x,y axes for the ellipse

    # size is the length of a side of the square
    # length is the length of the ellipse
    # defined as equal to the radius of the circle later

    my_label = np.ndarray(shape=(size, size))
    x = np.arange(1, size, 1)
    y = np.arange(1, size, 1)

    # inefficiently zero the array
    for i in range(0, size):
        for j in range(0, size):
            my_label[[i], [j]] = 0
            # print(my_label)
    for c in range(len(center_coords)):
        x0 = center_coords[[c],[0]]
        y0 = center_coords[[c],[1]]
        #theta = random.uniform(0, 6.28318)
        theta = 0.775

        for i in range(0, size - 1):
            for j in range(0, size - 1):
                xprime = (x[i] - x0) * math.cos(theta) + (y[j] - y0) * math.sin(theta)
                yprime = -(x[i] - x0) * math.sin(theta) + (y[j] - y0) * math.cos(theta)
                height2 = (0.5 * radii[c]) ** 2 - 0.25 * xprime ** 2 - yprime ** 2
                if height2 >= 0:
                    my_label[[i], [j]] = sqrt((0.5 * radii[c]) ** 2 - 0.25 * xprime ** 2 - yprime ** 2)

    return my_label

size = 128
radii, centers = circle_randomizer()
#print(radii)
#print(centers)

#Make labels and samples consistent with rest of code
N = 100
circle_images = []
ellipse_images = []
coords = []
for sample in range(0, N):
    blank_image = create_blank_image(size)
    radii, centers = circle_randomizer()
    temp_image = image_creator(centers, radii, blank_image, size)
    circle_images.append(temp_image)
    temp_output = make_ellipses(size, radii, centers)
    ellipse_images.append(temp_output)
    coords.append(centers)
#print(labels)
#print(samples[0][40])

#Storing the images in files:

filenames = []
for i in range(0,N):
  np.save('ellipses_' + str(i) + '.npy', ellipse_images[i])
  filenames.append('ellipses_' + str(i) + '.npy')
  np.save('circles_' + str(i) + '.npy', circle_images[i])
circles_stack = np.stack(circle_images,axis=0)
ellipses_stack = np.stack(ellipse_images,axis=0)
np.save('ellipses_stack.npy', ellipses_stack)
np.save('circles_stack.npy', circles_stack)

#Loading the images:

# load training images and corresponding "labels"
# training samples
training_images_path = 'circles_stack.npy'
labels_path = 'ellipses_stack.npy'

X = np.load(training_images_path,'r')/20.
y = np.load(labels_path,'r')/20.

#Defining the image preprocessing functions:
#(I'm not sure why preprocessing_X and preprocessing_y are different; this is
#code I've partially adopted from a research paper.)

# Preprocessing for training images
def preprocessing_X(image_data, image_size):
    image_data = image_data.reshape(image_data.shape[0], image_size[0], image_size[1], 1)
    image_data = image_data.astype('float32')
    image_data = (image_data - np.amin(image_data))/(np.amax(image_data) - np.amin(image_data))
    return image_data


​
# preprocessing for "labels" (ground truth)
def preprocessing_Y(image_data, image_size):
    n_images = 0
    label = np.array([])
    for idx in range(image_data.shape[0]):
        img = image_data[idx,:,:]
        n, m = img.shape
        img = np.array(OneHotEncoder(n_values=nb_classes).fit_transform(img.reshape(-1,1)).todense())
        img = img.reshape(n, m, nb_classes)
        label = np.append(label, img)
        n_images += 1
    label_4D = label.reshape(n_images, image_size[0], image_size[1], nb_classes)    
    return label_4D
Preprocessing the images:

# Split into train/test and make the shapes of tensors compatible with tensorflow format
nb_classes = 10
target_size = (128, 128)

#Below line randomizes which images are picked for train/test sets. ~20% will go to test.
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 42)
X_train = preprocessing_X(X_train, target_size)
X_test = preprocessing_X(X_test, target_size)
y_train = preprocessing_Y(y_train, target_size)
y_test = preprocessing_Y(y_test, target_size)


#The encoder-decoder model that I'm using right now:
def model_shape(input_img, nb_classes = 2):
   x = Convolution2D(2, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(input_img)
   x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)
   x = Convolution2D(4, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
   x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)

   x = Convolution2D(4, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
   x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
   x = Convolution2D(2, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x) 
   x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)

   x = Convolution2D(nb_classes, (3, 3), activation = 'linear', padding='same')(x)
   x = Convolution2D(nb_classes, (1, 1), activation = 'linear', padding='same')(x)
   #x = Reshape((target_size[0] * target_size[1], nb_classes))(x)
   output = Activation('softmax')(x)

   return Model(input_img, output)

#Defining dice loss:
smooth = 1

def dice_coef(y_true, y_pred):
    y_true_f = K.flatten(y_true)
    y_pred_f = K.flatten(y_pred)
    intersection = K.sum(y_true_f * y_pred_f)
    return (2. * intersection + smooth) / (K.sum(y_true_f) + K.sum(y_pred_f) + smooth)


def dice_coef_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    return -dice_coef(y_true, y_pred)

#Compiling the model:

nb_classes = 2
input_img = Input(shape=(target_size[0], target_size[1], 1)) 

model = model_shape(input_img)
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=dice_coef_loss, metrics = [dice_coef])
callback_tb = TensorBoard(log_dir='/tmp/Deconvoluter', histogram_freq=0,
                          write_graph=True, write_images=False)

model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=10, batch_size=32, 
          validation_data=(X_test, y_test))

model.save("/content/artificial_label_train.h5")
model.save_weights("/content/artificial_label_train_weights.h5")
print('Saved model and weights to disk.\n')
```

The code will compile up until this point, but returns an error after the following block of code:

```
# Loading models and obtaining softmax output (pixel-wise predictions)
def get_decoded_imgs(input_imgs, filepath, nb_channels = 2):
    model = load_model(filepath)
    decoded_imgs = model.predict(input_imgs)
    decoded_imgs = decoded_imgs.reshape(input_imgs.shape[0], target_size[0], target_size[1], nb_channels)
    print("FCN output obtained\n")
    return decoded_imgs

decoded_imgs = get_decoded_imgs(X_test, '/content/artificial_label_train.h5')

Outputs = {}
for i in range(X_test.shape[0]):
  decoded_img = decoded_imgs[i,:,:,1]
  #dictionary = OrderedDict()
  Outputs[i] = decoded_img

print('Plotting the results...\n')
plt.figure(figsize=(16, 8), dpi = 96)
for i in range(1, 5):
  FCN_output = Outputs[i-1]
  ax = plt.subplot(3, 5, i)
  plt.imshow(output,cmap='gray')
  print(FCN_output.shape)
  plt.title('output {0}'.format(i), fontsize = 10)
  ax.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
  ax.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
  plt.tight_layout()
  print('output' + str(i) + '\n' + str(output))
  print(np.max(y_test[i-1]),np.max(output))
plt.show()
```

The error is "Unknown loss function:dice_coef_loss" even though dice_coef_loss is clearly defined.

The input is supposed to be images of circles; the ground truth on which the neural network is trained is supposed to be images of ellipses.

The most recent encoder-decoder Keras model that I have used so far is shown in the code above; it returns ~55% val_dice_coeff, but this can probably be improved by adding more epochs. I used to use a simple CNN with mse loss which only returned lower-resolution images of the inputs.

What I am having problems with now is understanding why I am getting the error when I try to use model.predict() with dice loss as the loss function.

Comment: when you say convert the cricle to ellipse, is there any logic behind it ? or what are the factors that affect the conversion ? do you have some numerics behind it ?

Comment: Venkata, the idea is to have the neural network be trained to do the conversion given an arbitrary image of circles. This is a preliminary step in a greater project involving convolution and deconvolution of real images.

Comment: can you change the loss function to dice loss ? or IoU ? instead of mean square error

Comment: Venkata, I am sorry for the long delay, but this past weekend I have attempted to implement dice loss in my model, but I get the error "unknown loss function: dice_coeff_loss" even though I have defined it as a function in my code.

Comment: can you add the code here ?

Comment: Venkata, I have edited my post to include the code as requested. Thank you so much for your help so far, by the way. I would greatly appreciate it if you could continue to assist me.

Comment: were you able to call the dice_coef_loss function normally ? before mentioning it in the loss ?

Comment: I am able to call it in the following way in the code: dice_coef_loss(y[0], X[0]), which returns "<tf.Tensor 'Neg_1:0' shape=() dtype=float64>"

Comment: then you must be able to call it while mentioning it at loss also. I am not sure, what are we missing here.